# gems not found even though they are installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openproject

I am an absolute beginner when it comes to Ruby - I just follow a step by step tutorial to install OpenProject.

Right now I have problems with the following line of command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
```

It returns

> Could not find rake-11.3.0 in any of the sources

When I check the ruby version with "ruby -v" it prints

> ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]

Now, when I check for rake:

```
gem list | grep rake
```

the output is:

> rake (12.0.0)

... so why is it complaining that it could not find rake-11.3.0 even tough version 12 is installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `gem list`, please try `bundle show` to make sure you have installed the gems.

Comment: It says: Could not find activesupport-5.0.0.1 in any of the sources

Comment: Don't know why you want to install OpenProject by hand, but if you want to run it in a production environment I recommend using a [packaged installation](https://packager.io/gh/opf/openproject-ce)

Answer (score 1):

You application seems to have a hard dependency on rake 11.3.0, i.e. 12.0.0 is not acceptable to it.

Have you run Bundler first?

Run this command and it should install the version of rake you need, then your original command should work:

```
bundle
```

Comment: Shows an error: An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Do what it says: `gem install json -v '1.8.3'`. Install dependencies if needed.

Comment: Ok, bundle not completing successfully sounds like the root cause of your problem. Are you on Windows, I have seen issues installing json there before.

Comment: When I do what it says an other error appears: `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`
No, I am on CentOS...

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you don't have the necessary C build tools installed. I don't really use CentOS, but this suggests that yum groupinstall "Development Tools" might help: http://www.asim.pk/2010/05/28/build-essentials-in-centos/

Comment: @user1658080 just google that json issue, it's common. Then get back to bundle and you'll probably be fine

Answer (score 0):

meaning you have to downgrade your rake version to version 11.3.0

you may try this command

```
bundle update rake
```

this will try to update just rake to follow your setting in your Gemfile